# Create JSON from a plain string using pojo

Tags: java, json, string, pojo

I have a plain string in java as given below

```
Roll: 1
Name: john
Roll: 2
Name: jack
Roll: 3
Roll: 4
Name: julie
```

See here for roll 3 name is missing,

I want to convert above string to a json like given below,

```
{ "block":[ { "Roll":"1", "Name":"john" }, { "Roll":"2", "Name":"jack" }, { "Roll":"4", "Name":"julie" } ] }
```

how can I achieve it using java, gson and pojo.

Comment: You have objects or string?

Comment: I have a plain string, not able to get the logic how to map name with the roll number

Comment: You have a string and want to convert that string to json string?

Comment: it should not be a plain json , it should have the format that I have mentioned above

Comment: I think, you question is little confusing what you have initially? What are these `Roll` and `Name`? properties of an object and you have a List of that object, which you need to convert to json format you mentioned?

Comment: No I have one plain java string, I want to convert it to a proper json string, formats I have already mentioned for both.

Comment: Then you need to parse that string manually to some object and then you can convert it to json string using Gson or any other library

Comment: Yes that I want to know, what should be the algo or dynamic logic to parse this string to object If I have 100 roll numbers like these

Comment: May be you can read line by line and keep a pointer and at each odd line, initialise the object and then assign the next 2 lines to that object, notice you would have to split each line by `:` also to get the value. Forgot you have a string, so you may need to break it by new line character.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here's what i suggest:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import com.google.gson.Gson;

public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Gson gson = new Gson();
        String s = "Roll: 1\nName: john\nRoll: 2\nName: jack\nRoll: 3\nRoll: 4\nName: julie";
        String[] values = s.split("\n");
        List<Obj> objects = new ArrayList<Obj>();
        for(int i = 0; i < values.length - 1; i++){
            Obj o = new Obj(0, null);
            if(values[i].startsWith("Roll")){
                o.Roll = Integer.parseInt(values[i].split(":")[1].trim());
                if(values[i + 1].startsWith("Name")){
                    o.Name = values[i + 1].split(":")[1];
                    i++;
                } else {
                    o.Name = null;
                }
            }
            objects.add(o);
        }
        EndResult result = new EndResult();
        result.block = new Obj[objects.size()];
        for(int i = 0; i < objects.size(); i++){
            result.block[i] = objects.get(i);
        }
        System.out.println(gson.toJson(result));
    }
}

class EndResult{
    Obj[] block;
}

class Obj{
    int Roll;
    String Name;

    Obj(int Roll, String Name){
        this.Roll = Roll;
        this.Name = Name;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, Exactly what I was looking for, really helped.